# Simple window: Why is my dynamically generated button not shown?

Tags: c#, gtk#

I have a simple GTK# window: It only contains a button.

If I click this button, i want to create another button, which should be shown in the same window.

My problem is: The generated button is never shown on the GUI although it is added to my "Window" object.
The function I use to create the button works ok if I call it directly in the constructor, so it should be ok.

What code is missing in my simple application so that the generated button is shown?

```
class TestWindow : Window
    {
        private Fixed _fix = new Fixed();

        public TestWindow() : base("Test window")
        {
            SetDefaultSize(250, 200);
            SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);

            DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };

            Button bt = new Button("Create button");
            bt.Clicked += delegate (object o, EventArgs args)
            {
                addButton(80,80); //does not work
            };


            _fix.Put(bt, 20, 30);

            Add(_fix);
            ShowAll();
        }

        public void addButton(int x, int y)
        {
            Button bt = new Button("DYNAMIC");
            _fix.Put(bt, x, y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to this

```
 public void addButton(int x, int y)
    {
        Button bt = new Button("rolund");
        _fix.Put(bt, x, y);
        bt.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your addButton is missing a call to Add().

Comment: I dont need to call "Add" because I add the button to the "Fixed" container, which is already added to the window itself...